# regex with optional capturing groups and negative lookahead

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

This problem has been with me for quite some time. Here is the base of a string I'd like to search for:

`aa.bb.cc`

Each token (tokenized by '.') can be succeeded/followed with zero or more groups of array indexing:

e.g. `aa[1].bb[2][3].cc`

If my text contains a string with the exact number of tokens with optional array indexing, I would like to match. However, if the text I want to search includes an extra '.' and token, I do not want any match:

e.g `aa[1].bb[2].cc.dd`

I'm having trouble finding a pattern which includes the optional array index group(s) with a negative lookahead - I've been using `(?!\.)` - as the last part of the pattern. Here is one of the patterns I've attempted:

```
((\w+)([\[\]\w]+)*\.(\w+)([\[\]\w]+)*\.(\w+)([\[\]\w]+)*)(?!\.)
```

If my search string is `aa[1].bb[2][3].cc` the groups are as follows:

1. aa[1].bb[2][3].cc
2. aa
3. [1]
4. bb
5. [2][3]
6. cc
7. None

However, if my search string contains one more token, or even just '.', as stated above I want the entire match to fail. However, the search returns the same match groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this pattern, it will capture 3 sets anywhere:

```
(?<!\.)\b((?:(?:\w+(?:\[\d+\])*)\.){2}(?:\w+(?:\[\d+\])*))(?![\w\.])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tJ3rJ2/6)

Comment: This seems to do the trick, if I change {2} to {n} where n = number of tokens - 1.

Comment: number of tokens - 1 is right, please mark it solved.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the start-of-string anchor `^` to the beginning and the end-of-string anchor `$` to the end of your regex will cause it to match only strings containing exactly what you described and nothing more.

```
>>> regex = re.compile('^((\w+)([\[\]\w]+)*\.(\w+)([\[\]\w]+)*\.(\w+)([\[\]\w]+)*)$')
>>> regex.findall('aa[1].bb[2][3].cc')
[('aa[1].bb[2][3].cc', 'aa', '[1]', 'bb', '[2][3]', 'cc', '')]
>>> regex.findall('aa[1].bb[2][3].cc.dd')
[]
```

Comment: Thanks Greg. This works unless my search string is, for example, bound by '(' ')': `(a[1].b[2][3].cc)`

Answer (score 0):

You can bound the repeat number of `((\w+)(\[\d+\])*\.)` by 2 then add `(\w+)(\[\d+\])*` at the trailing of your regex. And don't forget to use start-end anchors.

```
^((\w+)(\[\d+\])*\.){2}(\w+)(\[\d+\])*$
```

See the demo: https://regex101.com/r/jG3uK7/7

Answer (score 0):

With regex shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/tJ3rJ2/4)
I get desired match.

Use negative lookahead and lookbehind.

`(?<!\.)\w{2}(\[\d+])*\.\w{2}(\[\d+])*\.\w{2}(\[\d+])*(?!\.\w+)`